# please help me understanding this function's implementation

Tags: java, discrete-mathematics

I tried to write a function. This function is given a function f from {1, 2, . . . , n} to the set of integers, determine whether f is one-to-one

I wrote this code but something this wrong.

```
public class Main {

public static void isBijective(int A[],int B[]){

    int i,j,count;

    for(i = 0;i<B.length;i++){

        B[i]=0;
    }

    count = 0;

    for (j=0;j<A.length;j++){

        if (A[j]==0){

            A[j] = 1;
            count = count+1;

        }
    }

    if (count==B.length){

        System.out.println("is bijective");

    }else{
        System.out.println("not bijective");
    }
}



    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int A[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
        int B[] = {1,2,3,4,5};


        isBijective(A,B);

    }
}
```

My code is entering the else statement every time.

Comment: If your code isn't doing what it should then use a debugger and fix your code

Comment: Go back and re-do your algorithm with pencil and paper.  What you've got here will obviously never work since your count is based on the number of 0s in A, which contains none.

Comment: What's the point of any of that? None of your `A` arrays have a `0` value, so `count` stays 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting all your B[] values to 0 and all your A[] values to 1. Also, your count is equal to 0 which will always equal n so unless you have an array of length 0 you will always end up with it going to the else statement. You need to restructure your code.